# How to add cursor blinking effect using Javascript in the below example

Tags: javascript

How to add cursor blinking effect using Javascript in the below example, How can we make the cursor at the end to blink? Can you please let me know a simplest way of doing it?

I appreciate any help.

```js
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.1em solid #666 }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
  };
```

```css
html,body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 3em 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #222;
  color: #aaa
}

h1,h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
}
h1 { font-size: 3.5em; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h1>This pen is
  <span
     class="txt-rotate"
     data-period="2000"
     data-rotate='[ "nerdy.", "simple.", "pure JS.", "pretty.", "fun!" ]'></span>
</h1>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/CheeseTurtle/pen/jzdgI

Comment: Try [this codepen](https://codepen.io/ArtemGordinsky/pen/GnLBq) by a guy called Artem Gordinsky.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might help! :)

```js
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```css
html,body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 3em 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #222;
  color: #aaa
}
@keyframes blink {
 from { opacity: 1; }
 to { opacity: 0; }
}
h1,h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
}
h1 { font-size: 3.5em; }
h2 {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.wrap {
  border-right: .05em solid;
  animation: caret 1s steps(1) infinite;
}
@keyframes caret {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200,100,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<h1>This pen is
  <span
     class="txt-rotate"
     data-period="2000"
        data-rotate='[ "nerdy.", "simple.", "pure JS.", "pretty.", "fun!" ]'>
    <i></i>
  </span>
</h1>
<h2>A single &lt;span&gt; is all you need.</h2>
```

Comment: Great, can you please insert it accordingly here https://codepen.io/CheeseTurtle/pen/jzdgI and share the complete code please? Cos, I couldn't see any change.

Comment: @Suhas as in merge..because that code has blinked by use of js I haven't use js..i've just used css!

Comment: I understand, can you please share the complete CSS script?

Comment: I think you have shared a general example of blinking a cursor using CSS.

Comment: yes!!!! you have to work on your code your self!!! here we'all can give you suggestion..we are not here to merge correct code in your present code..it did solve your problem so you should mark this correct :)

Comment: Well my question is "How to add cursor blinking effect using Javascript in the below example" 
I will certainly accept your answer if you can let me know how. you have given an example of blinking input cursor which is completely different. (https://jsfiddle.net/dygxxb7n/)

Comment: If you think you are not here to merge your code to a small example and make it work, please do not answer my question. Simple as that :)

Comment: my apologies @Suhas in understood your question later :) I thought you are not making effort to make your code work I misunderstood you by mistake :(

Comment: also updated my answer with your changes..hope it helps you :) @Suhas one more thing..add css tag into it